# Laravel: Code searches mailable in the wrong place

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to send an email in my project.
The action:

```
public function priceQuotePost(Request $request){
    $email = $request->email;

    Mail::to($email)->send(new priceQuoteThanks());

    return view('front.priceQuoteThanks');
}
```

I included the mail facade at the start of the controller (after the namespace).

The error:

> FatalErrorException Class
>   'App\Http\Controllers\priceQuoteThanks' not found in
>   FrontController.php (line 58)

The class is in the `app\Mail` folder

Comment: add `use App\Mail\priceQuoteThanks;` at the top of your file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just import it at the top like this :

```
use App\Mail\priceQuoteThanks;
```

if the is in `app\Mail` folder so the namespace will be : `App\Mail\priceQuoteThanks`